# How to make a contact form in wordpress call another php file

Tags: php, html, wordpress, forms

I am trying to add a small contact form in the sidebar of my WordPress site.  I transferred my code from it's original html file into the appropriate WordPress php files.  The only thing that isn't working is the contact form.

When I click on the send button it goes to the mailer.php file in the URL bar instead of sending the message.

This is the form:

```
<div class="w3-container w3-padding w3-white">
<h4 class="w3-left">Contact</h4>
<br> <br>
<div id="form-messages">&nbsp;</div>
<form id="ajax-contact" class="w3-container w3-margin" action="mailer.php" method="post">
<div class="w3-row w3-section field"><label for="name">Name:</label> <input id="name" class="w3-input w3-border" name="name" required="" type="text"></div>
<div class="w3-row w3-section field"><label for="email">Email:</label> <input id="email" class="w3-input w3-border" name="email" required="" type="email"></div>
<div class="w3-row w3-section field"><label for="message">Message:</label> <textarea id="message" class="w3-input w3-border" name="message" required=""></textarea></div>
<div class="field"><button class="w3-button w3-blue w3-ripple w3-section" type="submit">Send</button></div>
</form></div>
```

This is the mailer.php file:

```
<?php
    // My modifications to mailer script from:
    // http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/create-ajax-contact-form
    // Added input sanitizing to prevent injection

    // Only process POST reqeusts.
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
        $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["name"]));
                $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
        $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        $message = trim($_POST["message"]);

        // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
        if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
            http_response_code(400);
            echo "Oops! There was a problem with your submission. Please complete the form and try again.";
            exit;
        }

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "jerry@jerrylcrews.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        // Send the email.
        if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
            // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
            http_response_code(200);
            echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.";
        } else {
            // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
            http_response_code(500);
            echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
        }

    } else {
        // Not a POST request, set a 403 (forbidden) response code.
        http_response_code(403);
        echo "There was a problem with your submission, please try again.";
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a function like this to the onClick event.

```
function sendmail() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    var message = document.getElementById("message").value;

    var SendInfo= {     "name":name,
                        "email":email,
                        "message":message   };
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mailer.php',
            data: SendInfo,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                // Whatever
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain?  I could really use a step by step on this.  I'll try looking it up as well.  Any and all information you can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This function tells their client to load the file in url, with the post data specified in Sendinfo, without refreshing the entire page.  If you remove the submit class from your button, and add this function as onClick it will call your mailer.php with the correct post data, without refreshing the page.  It will then execute whatever code your put in the sucess function (you can use this to clear the form data or pop up an alert telling them the mail was sent).  I'd also use the absolute file path for mailer.php rather than the relative one for an ajax request.

Comment: Sidenote ajax is in the jquery library so you'll need to make sure to include that if you're not familiar with it.  Also the variable data will be whatever you print out in mailer.php if you want to receive feedback form the mailer.php page, or update things on your page based on the reply.

Comment: Thank you so so much.  I think I'm getting it.  I am doing this in a WordPress theme and I'm not exactly sure how to include the function you gave me.  If I were to make it it's own .js file, how would I make the button call it?  Is this possible?

Comment: Yep, if you make it it's own .js file the function should be accessible to add to the button as long as the .js is being included somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** ::
**This will stop the form submitting entirely. You will need to use ajax if you wish the form to not cause a page redirect.**

If you want to stop the form from redirecting you to mailer.php, then you will need to add a little javascript to cancel the request. Hook in to the button click event, and add "return false;" to prevent the page from changing.

Alternatively, submit the form using AJAX and you'll have more control over seamlessly submitting this info. :)

Comment: So are you saying I can't do it the way I have it set up now?

Comment: Looks like you have your answer but as @Mason Stedman above says, you use an ajax request to submit the form which is the way to stop your page refreshing or navigating away. The function supplied above is exactly what you need.